# Should we use insertRow() with acceptChanges()?

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset, cachedrowset

Here is a sample code in java:

```
    try {
        /* create connection */
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

        /* create a CachedRowSet */
        CachedRowSet cachedResult = new com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl();

        /* set connection information */
        cachedResult.setUrl(url);
        cachedResult.setUsername(username);
        cachedResult.setPassword(password);

        ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl");

        /* populate CachedRowSet */ 
        cachedResult.populate(result);

        /* close connection */
        result.close();
        stmt.close();
        conn.close();

        /* now we edit CachedRowSet */
        while (cachedResult.next()) {
            if (cachedResult.getInt("id") == 12) {
                cachedResult.moveToInsertRow();

                /* use some updateXXX() functions */

                cachedResult.insertRow();
                cachedResult.moveToCurrentRow();
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Now my question is this:
1. Should I use `insertRow()`? or I should use `acceptChanges()` instead? or maybe both?
2. where should I put `acceptChanges()` in this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You call `acceptChanges()` when you are ready to propagate the changes to the underlying data source. However, if you are doing a number of updates/inserts (for multiple rows) then you should call `acceptChanges()` after all `updateRow()` and `insertRow()` are done. The reason being when you invoke `acceptChanges()` you establish an actual connection to the database which can often be expensive. So calling it each time after each insertRow/updateRow for multiple rows is not efficient.

In your code I would put `acceptChanges()` after the while block ends. The reason is what I mentioned above - making the database connection only once after all updates have been done to cacheResult in the while block.

Comment: then why the javadoc for `insertRow()` says _Inserts the contents of the insert row into this ResultSet object and into the database_? if we won't call `acceptChanges`, it won't actually put it into the database, am I right? it'll just insert it into the row set. the same goes for `updateRow`.